# Need to transform file faster

Tags: java, text

I have a text file contains the data which contains some special characters like 'SOH' or 'STX' and ASCII value 13 and 10. I need to remove these characters and replace it with '\n'.

Right now I am taking each character at a time and replace the corresponding characters. The problem is my file size is in GB and it is reading each character at a time and do the operation.

This process takes a lot of time to complete. If I try to increase the character reading by more than 1, it gives me bad structure of file data.

I need a help in this to make this process faster or some other technique to transform these files.

```
char[] chars = new char[1];
for(int len; (len = reader.read(chars)) > 0;) {
  String head = new String(chars);
  fw.write(head.replaceAll(String.valueOf((char)13),"").replaceAll(String.valueOf((char)10), "").replaceAll(String.valueOf((char)2), "\n"));
}
```

Comment: You should use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read%28char[]%29 instead and read multiple chars at once, e.g. a buffer with char[512]

Comment: And also write them too - pecking byte by byte is a lot slower than taking in large amounts at once. In an idle rotating disk, you would need to spin up the disk, put the location under the read/write head, and read the byte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replaceAll is using regexes, and is taking O(n) time and space (it builds a copy of the string) each time it runs.

Therefore, `s.replaceAll(a, b).replaceAll(c, d).replaceAll(e, f)` would take 3x longer (both in time and in space) than a single scan. You really need to scan the string only once.

Also, you are reading/writing chars 1 at a time. Buffering reads is much, much faster.

Assuming plain ASCII, this will be a *lot* faster (it does not require extra space beyond the look-up table, and it does not require regex matching):

```
 boolean[] bad = new boolean[256];
 bad[13] = bad[10] = bad[2] = true; // add more 'bad' values here; assuming < 256
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
 BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(writer);
 char[] block = new char[1024*4]; // read in 4k at a time
 for (int len; (len = br.read(block, 0, block.length())) > 0;) {
     for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
         if (block[i] < 256 && bad[(int)block[i]]) block[i] = '\n';
     }
     bw.write(block, 0, len);
 }
```

Comment: No I can scan the string again. The only problem is the file size is very large.

Comment: You can scan it 4711 zillions of times, but that was not the point tucuxi made.

Comment: If you scan a string twice, you are effectively doubling the size of the file you're working with.

Comment: Added code: 4k buffer for both reading&writing (should amount to a orders of magnitude better performance) plus fast lookup of "bad" chars.